# Edit text input into an array

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Context: I am trying to make an application that allows me to have multiple edit texts (in a to do list format). I am using a linear layout with a scroll view inside of it so that I can allow users to have as many notes as they need.

Question: How can I put each editText inside an array, furthermore, how can I put the string contents of each of the editText in an array.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Show the code that didint work and what you tried. If you didint try anything, then please do before posting. This is why this question is downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all child views of parent layout in an array. use something as below. pass parent layout view to follow function

```
SparseArray<Edittext> array = new SparseArray<Edittext>();
.
.
.
private void findAllEdittexts(ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    int count = viewGroup.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup)
            findAllEdittexts((ViewGroup) view);
        else if (view instanceof Edittext) {
            Edittext edittext = (Edittext) view;
            array.put(edittext.getId(), edittext);
        }
    }

}
```

To get all edittexts text you can loop over that array and store in different array or list using gettext on each child.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get text from your EditText like this

`EditText et = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.et_nnnn);`

`string a = et.Text;`

And then add to your array